# libnet that properly calculates checksum on IPV6

Tags: generator, checksum, ipv6, packet, libnet

I have recently started playing around with libnet and using it to generate IPV6 packets.  I am very new at programming, however, I am quite happy with the library.

I have one problem with it though.  It seems that libnet currently does not have the ability to properly calculate checksums on IPV6 packets.  Being so new to programming, I am not yet capable of fixing this problem (although I am learning, so that one day I can).

I am curious, has anyone run across a version of the library that can do this properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What checksum? In IPv6, unlike IPv4, there is no checksum in layer-3 headers...